# Is it possible to switch view to tableview from same view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have a viewcontroller.xib which contains View, buttons,toolbarbutton, text box and a tableview. When I load the initial screen comes without table view which is fine. Now when I click on a toolbarbutton say, viewtable, I want the view to move to tableview. I have filled my tableview data with some default objects like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
       tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"object1",@"object2",@"object3",@"object4", nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"My Cell"];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"My Cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

So when I click on toolbar view button it should show tableview with toolbar button which also has a back button so when I click on that it should hide the table view and show the initial view. Is it possible to do all this in single xib? I can achieve the result if I create another xib and simply transfer control over to that xib but I wanted to know if its possible do this without creating a second xib file. And also for navigation I can use navigation controller but I want to check and see if its possible to use toolbar to transfer the control. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if your table view is inside your view, if not put it inside and set delegate of datasource to file owner, then in your view table method  write this code

```
-(void)viewTable
{
self.tableView.hidden = NO;
self.viewToolbar.hidden=YES;
}
```

On your back button code in toolbar write

```
-(void)goback
{   
self.tableView.hidden = YES;
self.viewToolbar.hidden=NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the first tip, that was the problem. I had to put my table inside the view and everything worked out well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need animation then you can do the following

1. Get a handle of tableView in your interface like this:

   @property(nonatomic,assign)IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
2. Hide your table view in initially ( like in viewDidLoad method )

   -(void)viewDidLoad
   {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.hidden = YES;
   }
3. Then in the method called by your toolbar's button do the following

   -(void)on_click_toolbar_button
   {
      self.tableView.hidden = !self.tableView.hidden;
      //This will keep toggling the table view from hidden to shown & vice-versa.
   }

Comment: I have created a property for tableview in my viewcontroller.h, but when I load only the view with default buttons and text gets loaded, tableview is not showing up initially(which is fine actually but not right). Do I have to set any property in my AppDelegate.m to show the table view?

Comment: make sure you bind the tableView's IBOutlet properly with the graphical tableView in xib/nib.

Comment: Yes, its binded, but still table view doesnt show up when running the program, only the initial view with default buttons and text gets appears

Comment: Ok, then just make sure you're placing the tableView inside the viewController and not outside floating in xib.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the hidden property to achieve that. Put these in the appropriate ibaction methods.

```
_tableView.hidden = Yes;

_tableView.hidden = No;
```

Comment: tableview doesnt show up initially so there is no need to hide, and setting the property to No also didnt brought up the tableview

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend to do this in two separate XIBs. The first should contain a `UIViewController` (your initial view) and the second a `UITableViewController` (your table view) class. Both should be handled by a `UINavigationController` - don't fight the API and try your own hacks if it's not necessary. The mentioned controller classes give you everything you need out of the box.

Comment: Florian this is not the case. Being myself a professional iOS Dev, I've used the tableView within one viewController without any problems.

Comment: Of course it is possible but, as said and due to what Gamerlegend asked, I do not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not recommended but you can do this by removing and adding tableview..